My .gitignore file is NOT ignoring anything
Is there any particular valid reason as to why my .gitignore file is ignoring the fact that I have told this file to ignore all of my newly-created, previously-uncommitted files that I have included in my .gitignore file?
Here is my setup:
#.gitingore
/hello/logging_config.py

#root
<Project>
   |--hello
      |---logging_config.py
|--.gitignore

Despite the fact that the logging_config.py file is included in the .gitignore file, it continues to keep the file with the status of untracked.
Even when running git status, it still returns:
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        hello/logging_config.py

I should not be seeing this. In addition, the capital U stays next to the filename in the Source Control panel. I fail to see why my .gitignore file cannot tell Git to ignore the file. What am I doing wrong here?
I double checked for any typos in the spelling of the file names. Added trailing slashed, removed trailing slashed. Added leading slashes, removed leading slashes. Restarted VSC.
Ran:
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Fixed untracked files"

Nothing worked.
Here is my directory tree
Update:
VSC is just returning silly, non-existent issues. I'm running the tree command, and it does not return half the files, I run run -a and it tells me there are no sub paths despite the fact that I can see the subfolders in the directory in the left held panel.
It is not recognising files despite spelling them correctly, it is giving me non-existent issues
Seriously, why does VSC make this so difficult? Why is this so impossible? Why is something that should be so simple be absolutely impossible? Why does this work for everyone else but not for me?
I am really getting to the end of my patience here. I just cant get anything to work! I could just scream.

@mkrieger1 Your suggestion has been updated on my post - so why am I still getting the same result then? Your suggestion did not resolve the issue. Why? The .gitignore file is in the  folder.

I think that was bad advice. The pattern should be hello/logging_config.py OR /hello/logging_config.py.

@mkrieger1 Great, so what's the mistake then?

Can you run the tree command and copy and paste its output? I want to verify that the project is set up how you say it is, in case your handmade diagram is inaccurate.

@alexis Great, updated. Still showing as untracked. Why am I not surprised?

Note that your comment says #.gitingore rather than #.gitignore. With several typos in your question it's hard for us to diagnose this. I suspect there's a typo or other minor discrepancy in your project that your question doesn't show.

I just saw the same! :-D OP is prone to typos, there could be one that is causing this problem ...

@JohnKugelman Right done the tree, wouldn't include the relevant file in hello nor the .gitignore file in the root so added them in.
What's the point of having a tree command if it doesn't include all of the files?

Thank you for the tree output. It looks like you've hand edited the <PROJECT> and .gitignore lines -- two lines that we care most about. Can you paste it again without the edits?

If it's not showing the files that are needed, that's an important clue! Don't "fix" the output. But do make it tree -a -- I forgot that it won't show files with leading dots by default.

@alexis I'm sorry but I'm stressed by this thing not doing as it's told & I'm really coming to the end of my patience with this. They are ALL underscored and they have now been corrected.
Why is this thing not doing as it's told? Sick and tired of nothing working. It's a piece of software, it should do as the user tells it to .

@JohnKugelman Well if the sodding tree actually included the relevant files in the first place when I would not have had to include them? What is the point of VSC having this feature if it only chooses which files to selected. Whoever designed this feature fo VSC clearly has zero common sense.

@JohnKugelman Jeez, this is so silly. I have run tree -a, the stupid bloody thing is telling me: No subfolders exist.  Of course they exist, I'm looking at them!
I'm just going to post a screen shot because I'm so sick and tired of VSC moaning at me about non-existent issues.
The stupidity of this is unbelievable. In all my years I have never come across some as so idiotic as this. Every little thing I do, it returns error messages, roadblocks and issues which do not exist.

An underscore and dot are different characters.
    hello/logging_config.py
                 X
      |---logging.config.py


I am aware of this & it's definitely an underscore

@JoJoJohan you mistyped it in your explanation, better correct it to avoid needless confusion.

@alexis I have just corrected my explanation on here, it was always an underscore in my repo.
Why is the .gitignore feature not doing as it's told?

I still read "Despite the fact that thelogging.config.py file is included in ..."

@alexis must be a lag

I have just tried out exactly what you said you have. It works as expected. Therefore, you must be doing something different than you described. Why don't you try it in a fresh project and see what you get:
mkdir fresh
cd fresh
git init
echo  hello/logging_config.py > .gitignore
mkdir hello
echo whatever > hello/logging_config.py
git status

I get this; what do you get?
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .gitignore

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

PS. This is an answer, since it (hopefully) tells the OP how to solve their problem.

Great, so why does it work for you & not for me? I'm sorry but things like this make me absolutely furious.
Update - now it's just decided it's going to work.
Amazing - spend the entire afternoon working this one out, getting absolutely fuming before it said You know what? I'm going to decide to to as I'm bloody told now.....
Anyway, thank for you for your input, much appreciated.

Strange … but all is well that ends well, right? But you didn’t say, did you try these steps in a fresh project? What happened?
